# Hibernate @IdClass - The attribute matching the ID class attribute site does not have the correct type "Site" but app works

Tags: java, hibernate

I have JavaEE project with Primefaces and JSF, using Hibernate to access the database. 
What confuses me is that application works fine but Eclipse says there is error in the @IdClass - The attribute matching the ID class attribute site does not have the correct type Site.

If in OperatorSiteCompositeKey class I change "Operator" and "Site" with Long then error notification disappears.

Please someone explain why this happens and how to solve this issue?

Thank you in advance!

```
@Entity
@IdClass(OperatorSiteCompositeKey.class)
public class OperatorSite implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="OPERATORID")
    private Operator operator;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="SITEID")
    private Site site;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Here is my composite key class

```
public class OperatorSiteCompositeKey implements Serializable {

    private Operator operator;

    private Site site;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on eclipse Oxygen.
It seems to be a related bug described [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=365011), when you try to use @IdClass to indicate to the JPA that you have a primary key composed by one or more foreign keys.